# Random motion in WiEngine Android

Tags: android

I am developing a game in Android using WiEngine. I want to know how the sprite in the game will move randomly? I am using the Random function.

```
   Random gen=new Random();
   xPos=gen.nextInt(widthX);
   yPos=gen.nextInt(widthY);
   sp1=Sprite.make(texture);
   sp1.SetPosition(xPos,yPos);
   sp1.setVelocityX(30);
   sp1.setVelocity(40);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move the sprites in Random motion you can use `MoveTo` method of `WiEngine`.
`MoveTo` method gives u a straight line motion.

```
MoveTo move=(MoveTo)MoveTo.make(duration,startX, startY,endX,endY);
sprite.runAction(move);
```

In the `startX`, `startY` u can put x,y values of what you want to put